# Black image when drawing Image on Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, graphics2d

I am working on a game in which I am use Canvas to display my graphics. I haven't (and don't plan on) using any Swing components...

In my render method:

I am using a BufferStrategy that I get from the canvas.

```
BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
```

Later in the same method I end up drawing images(entities, trees, map, etc.), disposing  of g, and showing the reference 'bs'.

```
...drawings onto canvas(entities, trees, map, etc.)
    //END RENDER
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
```

In between when I //END RENDER and finish drawing to g I ask if the game is paused. If so I am create a BufferedImage from what was made by g. I render that BufferedImage and then render my inventory screen on top of that:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(this.width, this.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        Graphics gx = img.getGraphics();
        game.paint(gx);

g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, Color.CYAN, this);       
interfaceLayer.render(g);
```

I am getting a black BufferedImage in my reference img.
Am I doing something wrong by using a BufferStrategy? Should I not be using two different Graphics objects?

Here is a picture of what it looks like before and after I pause the game to get an idea.
Instead of:

```
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, Color.CYAN, this);
```

I changed it to:

```
g.drawImage(img, 20, 20, Color.CYAN, this);
```

Just some arbitrary x,y so you can get the idea of whats going on with they layering.

[image]

[image]

Dont mind the gray box. It is a fillRect() that I will eventually be expanding as part of the graphics in my inventory screen.

Why the black image?

Comment: Painting is a destructive process, you are expected to completely repaint the current state each time, it won't accumulate paints from previous cycles. This is double important when dealing with a `BufferStrategy`, as a previous buffer may be dirty.  I'm not sure why you're rendering to a `BufferedImage`, it kind of defeats the purpose of using a `BufferStrategy`

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I want the img because I am running a Gaussian blur on it for the pause effect of a game. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Oh, well, that could be the problem, have you tried rendering the output without it?

Comment: Yes I have. My Gaussian blur technique is correct. I have created a completely separate program that demonstrates the algorithm I am using to blur. I have not yet implemented the blur into the source code for the game. I am still trying to get the correct img so I can blur.